# jPlayer 2.0 Elapsed/Remaining Time

Tags: jquery, html, cloud, webos, jplayer

I'm working with jPlayer 2.0

I've got it playing, pausing, etc...but how do I grab the elapsed/remaining time attributes from the jquery object? I've tried the event handlers and even provided HTML elements with the default selectors, but none of that appears to work.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 13):

I did it this way:

```
self.update_timer = function (event) {
    var status = event.jPlayer.status;
    $('.jtimer').text($.jPlayer.convertTime(status.duration - status.currentTime));
};


$('.jplayer')
    .jPlayer('setMedia', {
        mp3: mp3_link
     })
    .jPlayer('play')
    .bind($.jPlayer.event.timeupdate, self.update_timer);
```

The important is that `timeupdate` event sends status object with `duration` and `currentTime` properties that contain exactly what you need. The event is fired 4 times per second.

`$.jPlayer.convertTime` converts plain seconds (4225) into hours:minutes:seconds (01:10:25).

I don't know exactly if this was available in 2.0, but in jPlayer 2.1.0 that I use this is written in the [docs](http://www.jplayer.org/latest/developer-guide/#jPlayer-option).

Comment: ("Where should I ...") Wherever you need, just like $('element').click(...) handler can be defined anywhere. You may inline it: .bind($.lalala.timeupdate, function() { taram param });