# How can I get the current time of the song playing in jPlayer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jplayer

I used a jPlayer control to play a music part and songs.
I want to get the specific time during the jPlayer play, but i can't.

How can i get the current time of the song playing?

Comment: This is the first result on Google for "jplayer get current position", and the question makes total sense if you are working with JPlayer. Have a look at their API docs: http://jplayer.org/latest/developer-guide/ it's completely unclear how to get the current playback time from within an event handler (as evidenced by the complexity of the much upvoted answer!). IOW: This is a good question, and it should not have been closed. At most, it's a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6377441/jplayer-2-0-elapsed-remaining-time

Answer (score 10):

Take this:

```
$("#yourPlayer").data("jPlayer").status.currentTime
```

Also, take a look here: [jPlayer 2.0 Elapsed/Remaining Time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6377441/jplayer-2-0-elapsed-remaining-time)

Comment: i try it but it dosent work 
i want for example when the jplayer come to secound 5 show an alert message 
here is my code 
//if($("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer.status.currentTime==5)
 if($("#jquery_jplayer_1").data("jPlayer").status.currentTime=="00:03")
 {
 alert("hello");

});
}