# Change content of a div at specific time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jplayer

I am using JPlayer js library as an audio player. I want to change the content of a div at specific time of the song. In the code below `currentTime` has the time.

I want to make something like

```
if currentTime=='00:15' alert('track is now on 15th second');

if currentTime=='00:45' alert('track is now on 45th second');

if currentTime=='01:20' alert('track is now on 01:20th second');

if currentTime=='02:15' alert('track is now on 02:15th second');
```

But i'm unable to take `curretnTime` as a variable or assign its value to a variable. I'm newbie in js. Below is the actual code from jplayer

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var current_time;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
        ready: function () {
            $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                title: "Bubble",
                m4a: "http://www.jplayer.org/audio/m4a/Miaow-07-Bubble.m4a",
                oga: "http://www.jplayer.org/audio/ogg/Miaow-07-Bubble.ogg"
            });
        },
        cssSelectorAncestor: "#jp_container_1",
        swfPath: "/js",
        supplied: "mp3, oga",
        useStateClassSkin: true,
        autoBlur: false,
        smoothPlayBar: true,
        keyEnabled: true,
        remainingDuration: true,
        toggleDuration: true,
        cssSelectorAncestor: "",
        cssSelector: {
            currentTime: "#state1",
        }
    });
});         
</script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get the current time of the song playing in jPlayer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13785631/how-can-i-get-the-current-time-of-the-song-playing-in-jplayer)

Comment: ya i can get the current time. But i want to display a message at some specific times...

Comment: Take a look into the documentation: http://jplayer.org/latest/developer-guide/ The Paragraph **jPlayer Data** basically describes all you need in an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done that myself

```
<script type="text/javascript">

            $(document).ready(function(){
              $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({


              timeupdate: function(event) { 
              var time = event.jPlayer.status.currentTime;

                  if (time > 2) $('#comment').html('My first comment'); 
                  if (time > 4) $('#comment').html('My second comment');
                  if (time > 8) $('#comment').html('My third comment'); 
                  if (time > 15) $('#comment').html('My 4th comment');
                  if (time > 25) $('#comment').html('My 5th comment');  
                  if (time > 35) $('#comment').html('My 6th comment');
                  if (time > 50) $('#comment').html('My 7th comment');  
                  if (time > 60) $('#comment').html('My 8th comment');
                  if (time > 70) $('#comment').html('My 9th comment');  
                  if (time > 90) $('#comment').html('My 10th comment');
                  if (time > 120) $('#comment').html('My 11th comment');    
                  if (time > 150) $('#comment').html('My 12th comment');
                  if (time > 180) $('#comment').html('My 13th comment');    
                  if (time > 200) $('#comment').html('My 14th comment');

               },


                ready: function () {
                  $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                    title: "Bubble",
                    m4a: "http://www.jplayer.org/audio/m4a/Miaow-07-Bubble.m4a",
                    oga: "http://www.jplayer.org/audio/ogg/Miaow-07-Bubble.ogg"
                  });
                },
        cssSelectorAncestor: "#jp_container_1",
        swfPath: "/js",
        supplied: "mp3, oga",
        useStateClassSkin: true,
        autoBlur: false,
        smoothPlayBar: true,
        keyEnabled: true,
        remainingDuration: true,
        toggleDuration: true,
        cssSelectorAncestor: "",
        cssSelector: {
          currentTime: "#state1",
        }       
      });
    });
          </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like;

```
function messager(time){
    alert(time);
}
messager(currentTime);
setTimeout(messager(currentTime), 1000);
```

This function takes time as input. Also `setTimeout` function will call the function every 1 sec and run the code. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is set an interval to check your currentTime variable as the video plays. There are many ways to do this but here is a simple example of what you need to do.

```
function alertPlayerTime(){
    alert("Track is " + currentTime + " seconds in.");
    // other code can go here as well
}

setInterval(alertPlayerTime, 1000);
```

Send the function as a variable into `setInterval` and time is in milliseconds so you can check it how ever often you want. There are numerous posts in regards to this type of solution like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18957186/javascript-setinterval-clearinterval-simple-example-not-working-explained).

Answer (score -3):

I assume currentTime is updated by the player into an element with id 'state1'. What you can do is get it content and parse it:

```
var myCurrentTime = Number.parseInt(document.getElementById('state1').textContent);
```

and then use it in your condition.

To do so periodically:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    var myCurrentTime = Number.parseInt(document.getElementById('state1').textContent);
    .... handling logic here
}, 1000);
```

Comment: i want this myCurrentTime updated every second. Then only i can it in a loop and check time in if condition

Comment: @GijoVarghese did you read the link I gave you already? http://jplayer.org/latest/developer-guide/#jPlayer-data It's exactly what you need...